# log all requests coming to GCP cloud run gateway

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging, google-cloud-run, gateway

I have a Django backend running on cloud run, and I needed to log all coming requests/responses to cloud run instances, including the request body and the response body.
my first attempt was to create a Django middleware and use it to log everything, but I know it is much faster and more efficient to do it on GCP, as I use GCP as my logging backend.
how can I configure the gateway that sends requests to cloud run to log everything?

Comment: I'm not aware of a GCP mechanism to log the payloads (request/response bodies).  I found the following which seems to be a recipe to do the logging yourself in code writing to Cloud Logging.... https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/samples/logging-write-log-entry-advanced

Comment: You have to proxy your request. Either in other service, or directly in your service. If you use API Gateway, you can also imagine to log the requests through it (you can do it with Apigee)